# Why zipInputStream is empty though entry exists?

Tags: java, zipinputstream

I am trying to unzip archive, 
`zis.getNextEntry()` gives me `nextEntry`, I can see the correct name of the entry, but zip input stream itself is empty. Why?

```
byte[] htmlFile = new byte[]{};           
        ByteArrayInputStream bais =  new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(template.getKey().getFileBase64()));
        zis = new ZipInputStream(bais);
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        try {
             while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                if (!ze.isDirectory()) {
                    byte[] tempEntry = new byte[]{};
                    try {
                        zis.read(tempEntry);
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }                        
                }
            }
            try {
                zis.closeEntry();
                zis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Below is some debug info, where you can see - the entry exists, but nothing is read from the stream:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#read(byte[]))

```
public int read(byte[] b)
         throws IOException
```

> Reads up to byte.length bytes of data from this input stream into an
>   array of bytes. This method blocks until some input is available
>
> > This method simply performs the call read(b, 0, b.length) and returns
> >     the result.

Since length of `tempEntry` is 0 hence nothing gets read from the Stream